# can't access local mariadb mac: InnoDB error

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb

I am trying to setup MariaDB on my local machine.
Whenever I try to log in with:
`mariadb -u <mac_name>` or `mariadb -u root` I get this error:
using my mac password also doesn't work.
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

When I tail the logs found at `/usr/local/var/mysql/<host_name>.err` or `/usr/local/var/mysql/<host_name>.local.err` 
I get these errors:

```
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[ERROR] InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1
[ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption
[Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Does anyone know how I could get this working?

Comment: Is this your first attempt to use mariaDB or have you been using it before

Comment: @RiggsFolly first attempt for mariadb, but I had the same problem with mysql (5.7)